# Is it possible to populate member collection from a message in Discord JS?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to check if the message author has a specific role or not. The most common way I came across is the `message.mentions.members.first();`. But this would require the author to be mentioned in the message. So,

Is there a way to populate member collection and find if the message author has the role or not without mentioning him?

My current code looks like this:

```
//Some auth and import stuff here

let member = message.author;

//Some pre-validation stuff here

if(member.cache.roles.some(m => m.id === '608238654095360010')){

    message.channel.send("You are already verified!");
    return;
}
```

Before this I tried `member.roles.cache.some` but later found that discordJS got an update and became like above.

But I still get undefined error.

**Edit :** I tried using `message.member.roles.some` but that returns

```
TypeError: message.member.roles.some is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was using DiscordJS v12 which has quite a few updates.

Instead of using `message.member.roles.some`

I had to use , `message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.id === '608238654095360010')`